# How to share cl::opt arguments between passes?

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I have defined a cl::opt parameter in one of my pass.

```cpp
cl::opt<std::string> input("input", cl::init(""), cl::desc("the input file"), cl::value_desc("the input file"));
```

I wonder that how to share this parameter with another pass? I have tried to move it to a header file and let the another pass include it, but it reported a multiple definition error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make an option's storage external.

In some shared header file declare a variable:

```
extern std::string input;
```

And define it and the command line option itself in only one of your sources:

```
std::string input;
static cl::opt<std::string, true> inputFlag("input", cl::init(""), cl::desc("the input file"), cl::value_desc("the input file"), cl::location(input));
```

Note added `cl::location(input)` argument, which instructs `cl::opt` to store the command line option's value in the `input` variable. Now you can access `input`s value from different TUs, but still have only one definition.

Note that the variable that captures the command line option (`inputFlag`) is a global variable in the TU in which it is defined in. It is a good idea to give it internal linkage via the static keyword.

See [Internal and External storage](https://llvm.org/docs/CommandLine.html#internal-vs-external-storage) section.

Comment: Thank you! I find there may be a small problem that `cl::opt` should be declared as `cl::opt<std::string, true>`. This works for me.

Comment: I find another problem when running the compiled lib. `cl::init` cannot be used together with `cl::location`.